# Probability, Minmize Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a one problem that bugs me a while:

Two random variables with distribution $X$ is $\mathrm{Gaussian}(\mu=\frac{-3}{\sqrt5}, \mathrm{var}=\frac 9 5)$, and $Y$ is $\mathrm{Gaussian}(\mu=\frac{-2}{\sqrt5}, \mathrm{var}=\frac 4 5$).  Find the distance $k$ such that $\frac{-3}{\sqrt5}\le{k}\le\frac{-2}{\sqrt5}$ that will minimize $P(X>k)+P(Y<k)$.

How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normally distributed random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, its density is $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$  Consider $$g(k) = \Pr[X > k] + \Pr[Y < k] = 1 - F_X(k) + F_Y(k).$$  This function is minimized at a critical point of $g$; i.e., $$g'(k) = -f_X(k) + f_Y(k) = 0.$$  Now substitute the relevant means and variances, and solve the resulting equation for $k$. This will yield two distinct solutions; figure out which one corresponds to a minimum.